# When creating a builder with a superclass, parent cannot return instance of child class

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

If I am using the builder pattern to configure new objects I may have two classes like `Game` and `HockeyGame` (shown below). When I want to create a new `HockeyGame`, I get it's builder and start calling methods to configure the object as needed.

The problem I am running into is shown in the main function. Once I call one method from the super class it returns as an intance of `Game.Builder`, and I can no longer call any method from the child class.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Main.java

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        HockeyGame hg = new HockeyGame.Builder()
                .setScore(5)
                .setTimeLimit(3600)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
                .setIceTemperature(-5) // Error! Cannot call setIceTempurature() on
                                       // an instance of Game.Builder
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
                .build();


    }
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game{

    int score;
    int timeLimit;

    public Game(int score, int timeLimit) {
        this.score = score;
        this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        int score;
        int timeLimit;

        public Builder setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTimeLimit(int timeLimit) {
            this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
            return this;
        }

        public Game build() {
            return new Game(score, timeLimit);
        }
    }
}
```

HockeyGame.java

```
public class HockeyGame extends Game {

    float iceTemperature;

    public HockeyGame(int score, int timeLimit, float iceTemperature) {
        super(score, timeLimit);
        this.iceTemperature = iceTemperature;
    }

    public static class Builder extends Game.Builder {

        float iceTemperature;

        public HockeyGame.Buidler setIceTemperature(float iceTemperature) {
            this.iceTemperature = iceTemperature;
            return this;
        }

        public HockeyGame build(){
            return new HockeyGame(score, timeLimit, iceTemperature);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `getThis()` trick that is prevalent in much fluent API code.

First you need to make your `Game.Builder` generic in *itself*:

```
public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>>
```

Then you add a `getThis()` method:

```
public B getThis() {
    return (B) this;
}
```

Now you change your setters to return a `B` and `return getThis()` rather than `this`:

```
public B setTimeLimit(int timeLimit) {
    //...
    return getThis();
}
```

Your extension class also needs to be generic, in itself:

```
public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> extends Game.Builder<B>
```

Now you can use the code, and it will "remember" the intended type:

```
HockeyGame hockeyGame = new HockeyGame.Builder<>().setScore(10)
        .setTimeLimit(20)
        .setIceTemperature(-1)
        .build();
```

This final code looks something like:

```
public class Game {

    private final int score;
    private final int timeLimit;

    private Game(final Builder<?> builder) {
        this.score = builder.score;
        this.timeLimit = builder.timeLimit;
    }

    public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> {

        private int score;
        private int timeLimit;

        public B setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
            return getThis();
        }

        public B setTimeLimit(int timeLimit) {
            this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
            return getThis();
        }

        protected B getThis() {
            return (B) this;
        }

        public Game build() {
            return new Game(this);
        }
    }
}

public class HockeyGame extends Game {

    private final float iceTemperature;

    private HockeyGame(final Builder<?> builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.iceTemperature = builder.iceTemperature;
    }

    public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> extends Game.Builder<B> {

        private float iceTemperature;

        public B setIceTemperature(float iceTemperature) {
            this.iceTemperature = iceTemperature;
            return getThis();
        }

        @Override
        public HockeyGame build() {
            return new HockeyGame(this);
        }
    }
}
```

N.B: I have made the fields `private final` and also the main type constructors - this forces people to use the `Builder`.  Also, the constructor can take a `Builder<?>` and copy the variable from there - this tidies the code a little.

---

The actual hack is, as you may have noticed, here:

```
public B getThis() {
    return (B) this;
}
```

Here, we force a cast of the `Builder` to its generic type - this allows us to change the return type of the method dependant upon the specific instance being used.  The issue is, if you declare a new `Builder` something like the following:

```
public static class FootballGame extends Game {

    private FootballGame(final Builder<?> builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static class Builder<B extends HockeyGame.Builder<B>> extends Game.Builder<B> {

        float iceTemperature;

        @Override
        public FootballGame build() {
            return new FootballGame(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This this will blow up at runtime with a `ClassCastException`. But the `setter` method will return a `HockeyGame.Builder` rather than `FootballGame.Builder` so the issue should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I had looked at similar answers on SO, but thought that having a `getThis()` method seemed a little smelly. I guess it is acceptable smell though for the functionality it provides.

Comment: It's wonderful Boris

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

You explicitely cast it back to a `HockeyGame.Builder` object and work with its own method(s) on it.

The problem you had is that `setTimeLimit` returns a `Builder` object (mother class) and so you can not use the child methods on it.

```
HockeyGame hg = ((HockeyGame.Builder)(new HockeyGame.Builder().setScore(5)
                                                              .setTimeLimit(3600)))
                                                              .setIceTemperature(-5)
                                                              .build();
```

---

Also, `setIceTemparature` should return a `HockeyGame.Builder` object to be able to `build` on it.

```
public Builder setIceTemperature(float iceTemperature) {
    this.iceTemperature = iceTemperature;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: It is simplest way to have what you want, but generic builder is better approach.

Comment: @ByeBye Certainly but it was the easiest way to get there for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type-o. Fixed. Unfortuantely I don't think casting like you have shown is the best approach. It certainly would work as you have written it, but what if I had more function calls all interleaved. Would I put four or five separate casts? That's a bit dirty.

Comment: @JakeThomas Indeed, well I did my best :)

Comment: @JakeThomas you can build like this (class C cast) -> (all methods from builder C) -> (all methods from builder B) -> (all methods from builder A)

Comment: @ByeBye that seems like a good way end up in a mental asylum...

Comment: @BoristheSpider hah, sure, I just give solution for five casts :D